# MYSQL Stuck Generating temp table (massive query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables (1 to many):
*Dont say anything about that "email" relation. It is how my developer boss built it years ago.*

```
EMPLOYEES (+-50 results)
------------------------------------------------
id    name    
1     EmpName 1
2     EmpName 2  

CUSTOMERS (+50k results)
------------------------------------------------
id    name    email            employee_assigned
1     John    john@doe.com     12
2     Donald  donald@duck.com  6

INTERESTS_CATEGORIES (+650k results)
------------------------------------------------
id    customer_email    category_id
1     john@doe.com      97
2     john@doe.com      13
3     donald@duck.com   56
4     donald@duck.com   126
5     donald@duck.com   45

INTERESTS_PRODUCTS (+650k results)
------------------------------------------------
id    customer_email    product_id
1     john@doe.com      78
2     john@doe.com      23
3     donald@duck.com   19
4     donald@duck.com   56
5     donald@duck.com   45
```

So I need to filter the customers by their assigned employee and their interests. 
And here is the query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM          
(
    SELECT 
        customers.id                        AS 'id',
        customers.name                      AS 'first_name',
        customers.email,
        employees.id                        AS 'employee_id'
    FROM 
        customers, 
        employees
    WHERE 
        employees.id = 2
        AND 
        customers.employee_assigned = employees.id
) AS myCustomers

LEFT JOIN interests_categories 
    ON interests_categories.customer_email = myCustomers.email
LEFT JOIN interests_products 
    ON interests_categories.customer_email = myCustomers.email
WHERE       
( 
    interests_categories.category_id = 20
    OR 
    interests_categories.category_id = 21
)

GROUP BY myCustomers.email
```

**So, the problem:**

- If the employee has a low number of assigned customers (like 3) query
  is successfull.
- **If the employee has a medium-high number of assigned customers (over 100) query stucks.**

I execute SHOW PROCESSLIST and it is stucked "Generating temp table".

Anyone has idea? :(
Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the sub-query, and just use joins. Also, instead of the OR in the where clause, use IN. Lastly, make sure you have indexes on the email columns in each table, and on any columns that are used in the where or ON clauses.

Comment: I will try. Thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the indexes on your tables and try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS 'id',
    c.name AS 'first_name',
    c.email,
    e.id AS 'employee_id'
    ic.*,
    ip.*
FROM customers c
JOIN employees e
ON c.employee_assigned = e.id
LEFT JOIN interests_categories ic
    ON ic.customer_email = c.email
LEFT JOIN interests_products ip
    ON ic.customer_email = c.email
WHERE      
( 
    ic.category_id IN (20,21)
    AND e.id = 2
)
GROUP BY myCustomers.email
```

Comment: At best, it's misleading to include a GROUP BY clause in a query with no aggregating functions.

Comment: Well, I know something about sql, but I am not master. My work is php and jquery plugins dev, but now I am alone here with no SQL Master support. So, I found an ultra big query that does not work. (sry for my English)

Comment: @Sloan, adding indexes to emails fields works, but works my old query, not yours. Gonna try to make yours work, because mine does not show the results I want.

Comment: @SloanThrasher no, but 0 results. I told you the query is bigger than I show in this post. I am finishing trying to use yours, because your way is more logical than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, a less dumb design might look like as follows. If it was me, I'd start with this, and provide properly representative CREATE and INSERT statements accordingly. Also, I'm curious about where category_id comes from - because that's potentially an area for further optimization.

```
EMPLOYEES 
------------------------------------------------
employee_id name    
          6 EmpName 1
         12 EmpName 2  

CUSTOMERS 
------------------------------------------------
customer_id name    email            employee_assigned
          1 John    john@doe.com                    12
          2 Donald  donald@duck.com                  6

INTERESTS_CATEGORIES 
------------------------------------------------
customer_id category_id
          1          97
          1          13
          2          56
          2         126
          2          45

INTERESTS_PRODUCTS 
------------------------------------------------
customer_id product_id
          1         78
          1         23
          2         19
          2         56
          2         45
```

Comment: Less dumb design? What do it means? I am relative new at stackoverflow. category_id comes from a name associative table. category_id 1 means, for example, computers, category 2 kid toys, etc.

Comment: Well, this removes 'the email relation', doesn't it? So, less dumb.

Comment: I can not do this. I told that this is an old mega big database. New customers are synced every 1 hour, but interests are inserted before in a tedious proccess, so when the interest is inserted you only know the email, not the ID. I have to work with what I have. I can not make big changes because it could cause big errors and wasted time.

Comment: Next time I will provide create and insert querys. This is my first post about SQL and I did not know about that. Thank you for the help!