# MYSQL query taking too much time and times out

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to debug a MYSQL Query for its taking time around 4-5 minutes on one server and it fails on another MYSQL server.

The query is like this:

```
SELECT 
        *, 
        TM.tutor_id as tutor_id, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ) AS age 
    from 
        tutor_master as TM 
            LEFT JOIN category_master as CM 
                on TM.category = CM.category_id
            LEFT JOIN tutor_expected_rate TER 
                ON FIND_IN_SET( TER.tutor_id, TM.tutor_id ) > 0 
            LEFT JOIN admin_shortlist_master SHM 
                ON TM.tutor_id = SHM.tutor_id 
                AND (SHM.user_auth_id = 'c84258e9c39059a89ab77d846ddab909') 
            INNER JOIN level_master LM 
                ON FIND_IN_SET(LM.level_id, TER.level_id) > 0 
    WHERE 
        1=1 
    GROUP BY 
        TM.tutor_id 
    order by 
        TM.is_priority DESC, 
        TM.tutor_id DESC 
    LIMIT 
        0, 10
```

and MYSQL explain result is like this:

```
1   SIMPLE  TM      NULL    ALL     PRIMARY,tutor_id    NULL    NULL    NULL    27530   100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  SHM     NULL    ref     tutor_id,user_auth_id   user_auth_id    257     const   1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  CM      NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   toprecru_portal_db.TM.category  1   100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  LM      NULL    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11  100.00  Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  TER     NULL    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13223   100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Now my question is, it there any apparent mistake, which I am overlooking to make the query more efficient.
Thanks.

Comment: There's really no point SELECTing columns twice.

Comment: As @Strawberry said do not select columns twice, but even with selecting twice it should not execute 10 records for so long. Your tables must be very big and without indexes. Check on indexes

Comment: @Joshi . . . Start with a simple query (say from one table).  Add the tables one at a time.  Figure out what takes the most time.  Then ask another question.

Comment: Pls list all the indexes with their fields that you have defined in all the involved tables. Joining on find_in_set() cannot use indexes and will be slow. So, you may have to redesign your data structure. Pls show us the table structure and sample data from the tables where you store data in a comma separated format.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET cannot use an index, so, while blisteringly fast, it's unlikely to be optimal.

Comment: Also, you have no aggregating functions, so I've really no idea what you imagine a GROUP BY clause does for you.

Comment: Maybe you do not have indexes. Here is a link with a similar question I posted time ago: [MYSQL Stuck Generating temp table (massive query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339966/mysql-stuck-generating-temp-table-massive-query)

Comment: @Shadow - The main table is `tutor_master` having 150 fields, cannot make out how I post the table structure here.

Comment: Then post the relevant fields from the table at least.